# How to write a gRPC client in Python for a gRPC service written in Java

Tags: java, python, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-python

I am not able to move forward with this confusion as I don't know what to do. Most of the tutorials in Python get the main Class name where a method is defined, not sure how to do it when you just have to write the client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you're a beginner or intermediate programmer, so I'd be very surprised if you're tasked with or attempting something as complex as writing your *own* gRPC client. My guess is that you actually just want to read data from a Java gRPC service, and you've read about using a Python gRPC client, but you're confused about how to do that.

#### Simplified example of a client.

First, let's talk about how a *client* might work. Imagine writing a Python class like

```
class MyClient:
    def __init__(self, address, port):
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        // create a grpc channel

    def connect(self):
        // connect the channel

    def read(self):
        // read the channel
```

Then in your main function you would create an instance of this client, using it to connect and read (or write) messages. So a client is just an object that does the dirty work of connecting to some place and reading messages off the wire for you.

The above is a poor example because that's not really how gRPC works. I just figured a more traditional connect-and-read example would be easier to understand. Now you see the connection between your main function and a generic client.

#### So, how does gRPC fit into this?

The whole idea behind gRPC is that you *don't* have to write a client. Look at it in steps like this:

1. Someone began by writing a .proto file that "defined" their service. They defined what kinds of endpoints this service would have, *e.g.* `getThings()`, `doThat()`.
2. Then they used a program or plugin (grpc-java) to *generate* a *mostly*-finished Java application. The unfinished parts being: exactly what `getThings()` and `doThat()` does.
3. They filled in that code... and done. grpc-java generated the whole server code for them, so their service is already up and running.
4. Now *you* want to read from this service, but in Python.
5. *You* just need to grab that same .proto file that they used to generate the Java service, and follow [these steps](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python/#generating-client-and-server-code) to *generate a client*. So you see, just as they used a program to generate most of their Java service, you're also going to use a program to generate a client for that service. (And not even "most." It generates a fully-functioning client.)

   ```
   python -m grpc_tools.protoc --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. your_java_service_proto_file.proto
   ```
6. In your main function, you just create an instance of that generated client (specifying an IP address and port to the Java service), and you're good to go:

   ```
   channel = grpc.insecure_channel('10.123.123.123:54321')
   stub = the_generated_thing.RouteGuideStub(channel)
   things_from_java_service = stub.getThings()
   ```

#### A summary and another way of looking at it

Think of gRPC as a *suite of programs* written by https://grpc.io/ that generates code for everyone.

Someone defined a service in a .proto file then used one of those gRPC programs (grpc-java in your case) to generate *most* of a server. Then they implemented the rest and deployed that server.

Now, *anyone* like yourself can feed that same .proto file through *another* gRPC program (grpc-python in your case) to generate a fully functioning client in a language of your choice. You load up this generated client in your main function and you're ready to interact with the server on the other side.