# gRPC - Using code other than Java to create a Service Implementation

Tags: eclipse, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-python

I'm a student. For my Distributed Systems project, I'm expected to create a gRPC project. I'm creating the project in Eclipse.

Two service implementation are to be coded in Java and the other is to be done in another coding language.

I've tried searching for help online but the results I'm getting are related to gRPC and how gRPC works, not about the coding or using other coding.

Ideally, I would like to use Python as the other language and to create it in Eclipse if possible. Does anyone have any information, documentation or examples I could look at, so I could can reference it?

I am able to see online searches for both Java and Python, but I'm not sure how to use both in one project.

Thank you.

Comment: See if my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649760/how-to-write-a-grpc-client-in-python-for-a-grpc-service-written-in-java/61787478#61787478 helps you along your way.

Comment: Maybe you can reference my code of how to use gRPC in Java [grpc-java-sample](https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample), and you can search grpc python on GitHub, there should be many project you can reference.

Comment: @slackwing, Thank you for your help. I get how to do gRPC in Java and in Python, but I'm just a bit lost at how to add both Java and Python into the one Project. I was thinking of just adding the Java and Python code in the one folder, but I can't run the (e.g.) Python in Eclipse.

Comment: @HelloWood ↑↑ Previous comment

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misunderstood. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I got a lot of feedback for lecturers and classmates.

The server doesn't care what programming language is used.

So Java, Python, Node.js etc, could all be sent to the server.

A generalised simplistic idea of how I was able to understand is: Python converts its code to binary and sends it to the server. Same with Java and Node.js.

I don't know why, but I was digging myself deeper trying to figure out what code (i.e. the binary) that needed to be the communication between the server and code. I was trying to encapsulate Python into Java and vice versa.

Why did I think this? Your guess is as good as mine.